Electron app auth0 SSO login with system default browser
I followed this auth0 electron app documentation to login inside electron app for auth0 but when an accaount is SSO(Single Sign On) electron BrowserWindow doesn't work like system default chrome and can't authenticate the single sign on users. But when I login on chrome directly chrome sees. How can I implement auth0 login in electron app as login works on system default chrome.
createAuthWindow() method uses BrowserWindow and it doesn't open system default browser for SSO.


const jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode');
const axios = require('axios');
const url = require('url');
const envVariables = require('../env-variables');
const keytar = require('keytar');
const os = require('os');

const {apiIdentifier, auth0Domain, clientId} = envVariables;

const redirectUri = 'http://localhost/callback';

const keytarService = 'electron-openid-oauth';
const keytarAccount = os.userInfo().username;

let accessToken = null;
let profile = null;
let refreshToken = null;

function getAccessToken() {
  return accessToken;
}

function getProfile() {
  return profile;
}

function getAuthenticationURL() {
  return (
    "https://" +
    auth0Domain +
    "/authorize?" +
    "scope=openid profile offline_access&" +
    "response_type=code&" +
    "client_id=" +
    clientId +
    "&" +
    "redirect_uri=" +
    redirectUri
  );
}

async function refreshTokens() {
  const refreshToken = await keytar.getPassword(keytarService, keytarAccount);

  if (refreshToken) {
    const refreshOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: `https://${auth0Domain}/oauth/token`,
      headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
      data: {
        grant_type: 'refresh_token',
        client_id: clientId,
        refresh_token: refreshToken,
      }
    };

    try {
      const response = await axios(refreshOptions);

      accessToken = response.data.access_token;
      profile = jwtDecode(response.data.id_token);
    } catch (error) {
      await logout();

      throw error;
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error("No available refresh token.");
  }
}

async function loadTokens(callbackURL) {
  const urlParts = url.parse(callbackURL, true);
  const query = urlParts.query;

  const exchangeOptions = {
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'client_id': clientId,
    'code': query.code,
    'redirect_uri': redirectUri,
  };

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: `https://${auth0Domain}/oauth/token`,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(exchangeOptions),
  };

  try {
    const response = await axios(options);

    accessToken = response.data.access_token;
    profile = jwtDecode(response.data.id_token);
    refreshToken = response.data.refresh_token;

    if (refreshToken) {
      await keytar.setPassword(keytarService, keytarAccount, refreshToken);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    await logout();

    throw error;
  }
}

async function logout() {
  await keytar.deletePassword(keytarService, keytarAccount);
  accessToken = null;
  profile = null;
  refreshToken = null;
}

function getLogOutUrl() {
  return `https://${auth0Domain}/v2/logout`;
}

module.exports = {
  getAccessToken,
  getAuthenticationURL,
  getLogOutUrl,
  getProfile,
  loadTokens,
  logout,
  refreshTokens,
};





const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const authService = require('../services/auth-service');
const createAppWindow = require('../main/app-process');

let win = null;

function createAuthWindow() {
  destroyAuthWin();

  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1000,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      enableRemoteModule: false
    }
  });

  win.loadURL(authService.getAuthenticationURL());

  const {session: {webRequest}} = win.webContents;

  const filter = {
    urls: [
      'http://localhost/callback*'
    ]
  };

  webRequest.onBeforeRequest(filter, async ({url}) => {
    await authService.loadTokens(url);
    createAppWindow();
    return destroyAuthWin();
  });

  win.on('authenticated', () => {
    destroyAuthWin();
  });

  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null;
  });
}

function destroyAuthWin() {
  if (!win) return;
  win.close();
  win = null;
}

function createLogoutWindow() {
  const logoutWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
  });

  logoutWindow.loadURL(authService.getLogOutUrl());

  logoutWindow.on('ready-to-show', async () => {
    await authService.logout();
    logoutWindow.close();
  });
}

module.exports = {
  createAuthWindow,
  createLogoutWindow,
};



